# Node.js EventEmitter inheritance not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, inheritance, coffeescript

I cannot seem to inherit the EventEmitter in my node.js.

The lines with @on are used to check for @emit but the console.log inside the @on block is never executed. I am really confused because I got inheritance of the EventEmitter working in another project but it wont work here. The src code is in the gist.

https://gist.github.com/z3t0/8d7a6eca218f35355476

Thanks

Comment: Please include relevant code snippets within the question text. You can use the `{}` button in the editor to format them as a code block.

Comment: You're only inheriting but you don't seem to be calling the `EventEmitter` constructor from your the `Gamemode` ctor. See [this example](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Hi, I have tried several times but some parts of the code always end up outside? Any help appreciated.

Comment: @robertklep I am assuming you mean 'events.EventEmitter.call(this);' I will try that and see what happens.

Comment: @RafiKhan The `super` call would normally attempt to cover that, but may be failing with using `inherit()` rather than CoffeeScript's own `extends`. Maybe they're equivalent.

Comment: @RafiKhan yes, that's what I meant, but I'm not too familiar with CF.